# Is it derogatory to call user a punter?

Tags: nouns, slang, offensive-language, connotation, terminology

I've been wondering whether it is somewhat derogatory to call a user a *punter*. For instance,

> We should encourage punters to participate in the discussions.

**Update:** My apologies — I owe you an explanation. I do a lot of User Experience work for an organisation (online service) where internally users are occasionally referred to as *punters*. Because *personas*, *customers* and *users* are centric to my line of work, it bothers me every time I hear a word that may even remotely indicate users' inferiority. You know what they say — "Great UX is cultural". I've read a few references, but because English isn't my first language I wanted to find out whether there is a subtle nuance beyond a dictionary definition.

Comment: This question needs some elaboration, I think. What is a _punter_ in this context, and why might it be derogatory?

Comment: As J.R said, without other elaboration, we can only tell you to be conscious of your choice of language: avoid jargon.

Comment: *Punter* is a standard British term which can be applied to users or customers.

Comment: Punter can also mean _one who punts_, which, in American English, means one who is prone to give up in the face of adversity.  I still think more elaboration would be nice – "users" is a rather vague word, too.

Comment: OP: Add context and some details, so we can know.

Comment: **The simple answer here is "yes"**, it couldn't be more straightforward.  Sure internally you may refer to your userbase as "punters" "idiots" "morons" "suckers" "the idiots who pay" or whatever. But obviously, of course, you would never use that term when talking to customers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/punter

> *noun*
>   **1** *informal*, chiefly *British* a person who gambles, places a bet, or makes a risky investment.
>   • a customer or client, especially a member of an audience.
>   • a prostitute’s client.

It certainly **could** be derogatory. It **does** indicate an off-hand or casual attitude to customer service to call consumers *punters*.

Comment: If the user is of a betting online application, they'd probably not get offended. It is a rather "low class" word though.

Comment: It's inconceivable a betting dotcom - which deals in billions of dollars and to which clients entrust thousands to millions of dollars - would use the term "punter". (Find an example.) UNLESS specifically their marketing took an incredibly jokey, whacky approach - but what companies that deal with money do that? The only online companies that deal with as much money as the gaming companies are (a) a few online brokerages and (b) the bigger online banks.  (cont...)

Comment: ... For all three of those categories, it seems inconceivable they would use slang terms, anything less than "irreproachable language".  Again, you MIGHT be able to find a casino, bank or brokerage that (for some reason) has a "whacky! offensive! slang!" vibe in their marketing. (Like if, say, Virgin Media has a gaming division, or some such.)  If anyone can find an example, it would indeed be such a "jokey! silly!" marketing vibe. the extremely short answer is **it's inconceivable you'd use that term normally** in marketing. (No more than McD. or Coke would refer to clients as "fatties".)